# how can i change magento default URL?

Tags: magento, url, magento-1.8

how can I change `magento` default URL?

[image]

Please help me out from this

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a Magento admin issue that belongs over on magento.stackexchange

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Log in to your Magento Admin Panel (Figure 1).

On the upper right, click System > Configuration.

From the menu on the left, under the General list, click Web.

Open the Unsecure and Secure dropdowns, locate the base URL line, and replace this with the new URL.

Clear the Magento cache and your browser's cache. The site should now load properly.